# How to make Django store datetimes in UTC but show them in local time in Admin?

Tags: django, datetime

What the title says. For simplicity and standardization, I want to store datetimes in UTC timezone, but I want to display them in Admin's local timezone. No matter the settings (`TIME_ZONE` and `USE_TZ`), I still have `Note: You are x hours ahead of server time` when editing my datetimes. I want this note to go away, and the flow to be like:

1. Type time in local time and click save
2. Datetime created will be saved in UTC timezone
3. When I get it from DB by request, it will still be in UTC. Conversion is handled by front end.
4. If I look at it from admin, it will be in local timezone.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone. 
Disclaimer: I had never used before